# Grunt file is not digitally signed

Tags: gruntjs

This is my 1st time using grunt. When I type grunt in the command line, I get the following error:

**The file [Path]grunt.ps1 is not digitally signed. You cannot run this script on the current system. For

more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.**

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you run a .ps1 PowerShell script you might get the message saying “.ps1 is not digitally signed. The script will not execute on the system.”

To fix it you have to run the command below to run Set-ExecutionPolicy and change the Execution Policy setting in windows

run this in powershell with administrative privilege :

Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope LocalMachine

This command sets the execution policy to bypass for LocalMachine.

Microsoft documentation :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.1